# 2000 people play chess, need to find the maximal number of games during the marathon if…

Tags: graph-theory

**2000 people play chess, each two play once. For every 2 players (which play in the same game) at least one plays not more than 30 games during the marathon. What is the maximal number of games in that marathon?**

I've done this:
Let's divide those 2000 player in two groups.
In the first group are those people who played less than 31 games during the marathon. (Let's call them "F" people)
And second group: Those people who played more than 30 times. (Calling them "M" people)
Let's make a graph with 2000 vertexes and every two are connected if 2 players played chess together.
Let's look at the vertex which has the most number of edges.
If it's F vertex, then all vertexes are "F" types. So in that case the maximal number of games will be $2000×30/2$.
If it's M vertex, well, then all people who played with him will be "F"s. let'ss suppose our first vertex  has the maximal number of edges that are possible, in that case, the maximal number of games will be $1999+(1998×29+28)/2=30984>30000$(case of absence of "M"s)
If we had two M vertexes (which would be connected to the others as well) the number of games would be $30969$ and it's less than 30984. Similarly if we add M vertexes, the sum decreases every time. So 30984 should be the maximum.

*But they're many shortcomings as we haven't talked about such cases when "M"s aren't connected to  all vertexes. Also, is it possible to say that if the pattern (of decrease) is visible, this means that we can judge the value of number?
So I think there's more effective and simple-idea solution for this problem.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have any games between $M$ people.  You should be able to convince yourself that you want few games between the $F$ people.  This suggests a bipartite graph.  Let there be $m\ M$ people and $f \ F$ people.  We have $m+f=2000$.  From the $F$ side there are $30f$ games.  Each $M$ person can play all the $F$ people, so there are $mf$ games from that side.  This gives $m=30, f=1970$ and there are $30 \cdot 1970=5910$ games.

Comment: If it's possible for two people to play more than once together, then there could be only one person in $M$, and you'd have $30 \cdot 1999 = 59970$ games.

Comment: @HugoManet:  that is prohibited by the problem where each two play once.